# Botão anterior desativa quando clicado no próximo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Eu tenho dois botoes que são criados de acordo com o que vem da api:

```
  <div class="col-2">                     
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success button-ok botOk" value="${element.NUMOS}" id="${element.COD_PROD}" onClick="sim(this);">SIM</button>                     
  </div>

  <div class="col-2">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger button-ok" value="${element.NUMOS}" id="${element.COD_PROD}" onClick="cance(this);">NÃO</button>
  </div>

<div class="col">
     <p class="prod">${element.PRODUTO}</p>
</div>
```

O COD_PROD são iguais nos botões SIM e NÃO.

O usuário final tem que clicar sim ou não, e como eu pego os dados da api, esse `${element.PRODUTO}` pode vim mais de 1, então eu fiz com um forEach para ele criar outra div com os botoes e nome do produto automaticamente.

Só que quando eu clico em sim em um produto, e vou clicar em sim no outro, o botão desativa do anterior clicado e só fica o atual clicado.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Código que faz alteração do status:

```
 $('button').click(function () {
                  var clicado = $(this); //captura o botao clicado
                  $('button').removeClass('ativo') // remove a classe dos demais botoes
                  clicado.addClass('ativo');// adiciona a classe ao botao alvo                
                })
```

Comment: poderia postar o seu código que faz a alteração dos status dos botões?

Comment: @AlvaroAlves pronto, coloquei na pergunta

Comment: "Só que quando eu clico em sim em um produto, e vou clicar em sim no outro, o botão desativa do anterior clicado e só fica o atual clicado."...
o seu problema está nesta linha: `$('button').removeClass('ativo') // remove a classe dos demais botoes`

Comment: Isso, mas tentei de varias outras formas e nao consigo resolver isso

Comment: vamos ver se eu entendi:
1 - Você clica em ok em um botão, ele adiciona a classe 'ativo';
2 - Você clica em ok em outro botão o anterior deve ficar com a classe "ativo"

Comment: é isso? caso clique em não ele remove a classe 'ativo' apenas do produto atual?

Comment: exatamente isso!!!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84590/discussion-between-alvaro-alves-and-maria).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando ele chama essa linha:

`$('button').removeClass('ativo') // remove a classe dos demais botoes`

Ele desativa todo mundo, imagino que a intenção seja remover o "SIM" caso tu clique no "NÃO" do mesmo produto. Se todo aquele bloco html que tu colocou na pergunta para um produto estiver dentro de uma tag html que englobe cada produto, tu consegue fazer...

`clicado.parent().parent().find('button').removeClass('ativo') // remove a classe dos demais botoes`

Fiz um [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/evandrobm/xpvt214o/888426/) pra demonstrar!

Comment: Quando clica no outro nao ta removendo a anterior, ta ficando com SIM e NÃO ativo

Comment: Atualizei, mas usando a linha que comentei aqui funciona